# Is it okay to use non-OEM USB-C cable and/or adapter for Macbook Pro?

Tags: usb, power

Is there anything special about the Apple USB-C cable, other than its quality, that would prevent me from using a USB-C cable from another brand?

And the same question for the [wall adapter](https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/MNF72LL/A/61w-usb%E2%80%91c-power-adapter?fnode=e4c7e79079bcd9d53dbe275b5613667641b6f177d805e4849f0f5b5f12f9f191b1e0619a54c2fd1417bd7148e4fea243d86018b39c91ab9bd48ec826c27cf7ebc796ac74baf31574d4a0b3abbc6e4bb570e0d6fef29501953a9c8ba62178c931).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that's 'special' about them is they are MFI-certified from Apple.  This means that Apple ensures it will work with all their devices.  Third-party accessory makers can also have their products MFI-certified by following the guidelines that Apple publishes.

The question of 'quality' is subjective in that what I think it means might be different than what you think it means.  I spent a lot of money on my Apple products so I will only buy MFI accessories (they could cost more money than non-certified products).

In this manner, any USB-C cable will work but it's up to you to decide if a higher-quality cable will give you the peace of mind that there's less a chance that the cable will fail or cause other problems for you.

Comment: Thanks for catching my misspelling, @patrick-brinich-langlois.  That was clearly the wrong word!

Answer (score 5):

A USB-C cable is a USB-C cable.  There's nothing special about it with the exception of quality (which you already mentioned.)

As far as adapters go, there are "genuine" adapters which are actually OEM'ed by a 3rd party company with Apple's blessing and then there are the myriad of knock-offs you can find on Amazon and eBay.

If you are using the USB-C charger/port to charge your device, technically speaking, any cable/adapter will do.  That said, when you purchase said cable/adapter, look for quality products, not the cheapest you can find.

What to look for...

- A [USB-IF compliance.](http://www.usb.org/developers/compliance/) This means it was tested to meet a certain set of standards.
- USB certified Charger Logo.  This means that the charger is USB-IF compliant.

  [image]

Does this mean that the no-name or off-brand products are bad?  No.  It means that the manufacturer has taken the time and cost to certify their products to a certain level of quality and performance.  (IMO) Saving a few dollars on a cable/charger is simply not worth it when attaching it to a $1000+ Mac that I use for daily work.